# Очистка оперативной памяти

Tags: c

Делаю сейчас программа со списком, и небольшая проблема в плане удаления и пришла мысль: можно ли как-то очистить все данные, занесенные в ОП, как при перезапуске консоли, только не закрывая ее и программу?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос сложнее и страннее, чем кажется. Потому что вы имеете дело с виртуальной памятью. А в ней, кроме хипа (в котором `malloc` выделяет место), находится исполняемый код и стек вызовов.

Comment: Это надо делать свой аллокатор памяти с автоматическим освобождением памяти

Comment: А что вы называете "очистить данные", это освободить память или  затереть ее всю нулями ? Если первое - то когда вы выделяете память malloc вы так же можете и освобождать ее с помощью free. На размер занятой памяти в ОС это не повлияет скорее всего, но с другой стороны обычно ничего страшного в этом нет, так как если память реально не используется она может быть вытеснена другими задачами, если им она понадобится

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему вы просто хотите, чтоб одним махом всю выделенную через malloc'и память освободить? Но откуда вы знаете, где в каких глубинах библиотек что было вызвано и выделено? можно легко напартачить.

А если такое хотите - то можно написать свой `malloc`, который, вызывая стандартный `malloc`, записывает адрес выделенной памяти в кокой-то список или массив например. А потом одна функция, которая освободжает все указатели из этого списка.

Только это будет больше проблем, чем толку.